# how to program to find the largest 2 numbers and the smallest 2 numbers in the array in java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

finding largest and smallest in array is known, as i done in my below code
but now how to print the **two** largest and **two** smallest elements from the array.

```
class twolargestsmallest 
{
public static void main(String args[]) {
int a[]=new int[]{2,20,34,12,67};
int smallest=a[0];
int largest=a[0];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
if(a[i]<smallest){
smallest=a[i]; }
if(a[i]>largest){ 
largest=a[i]; }}
System.out.println(smallest+" "+largest); }}
```

Comment: What is your question? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please ([edit] your attempts into this question - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Use two passes through the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Array.sort and get the 2 values from the beginning for the smallest and 2 values from the end for the largest

Comment: Needs probably a special case handling when there is only 1 value in the array, but else it should work. +1

Comment: Yes, reading the code i think that is better give a simple solution, it's not a complex structure array, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the style of your solution: instead of "forgetting" the latest min and max when you find a smaller/bigger number, just memorize them as second bigger / second smaller.

```
for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
    if(inputArray[i] > max)
        max2 = max;
        max = inputArray[i];
    else if (inputArray[i] < min)
        min2 = min;
        min = inputArray[i];

}
```

for completeness, check the size of the array and be careful of particular cases (e.g. all elements are equal).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] arr = {5,3,9,10,7,2,11,1};
    
    int min1 = arr[0];
    int min2 = 0;
    
    int max1 = arr[0];
    int max2 = 0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i] > max1) {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = arr[i]; 
        }else if(arr[i] < min1){
            min2 = min1;
            min1 = arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Max1 = "+max1+" Max2 = "+max2);
    System.out.println("Min1 = "+min1+" Min2 = "+min2);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
public class maxmin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {0,3,15,10,20,2,1,5};
        
        int min1 = arr[0];
        int min2 = arr[1];
        
        int max1 = arr[0];
        int max2 = 0;
        
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(arr[i] > max1) {
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = arr[i]; 
            }
            else if(arr[i] > max2) {
                max2 = arr[i];
            }        
            if(arr[i] < min1){
                min2 = min1;
                min1 = arr[i];
            }
            else if(arr[i] < min2) {
                min2 = arr[i];
            }
        }    
        System.out.println("Max1 = "+max1+" Max2 = "+max2);
        System.out.println("Min1 = "+min1+" Min2 = "+min2);
    }
}
```